# Using software in a GPL linux distribution

Tags: licensing

I am looking at different types of linux to run a small web server on, however I have a question as I am a bit confused about how the GPL works. If I have PHP scripts that I created myself, etc...running on the linux server, do those automatically become part of the GPL, or are those still mine to do with as I please? How about if I need to make a copy of the system, as is, by making a disk image, to install it on another computer of mine? Does that mean that all my work would become part of the GPL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is very likely that your Linux system will run Apache, which is not licensed under terms of GPL, but [Apache license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License). Apache itself does not run PHP scripts. In fact lots of functionality is provided by third-party modules and this applies to PHP too, which is handled by mod_php. Those modules are allowed to be distributed under their own licenses. And PHP utilizes this being distributed under terms of [PHP license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_License). PHP license is not permissive (or not copyleft), which means that you may distribute your scripts under any license you wish, with very little restrictions like including in your product a statement:

```
This product includes PHP software, freely available from <http://www.php.net/software/>
```

So basically no, your software will not become a part of GPL in any way.